# How should I access a virtual attribute from an associated model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, has-and-belongs-to-many, virtual-attribute

I have two models which are associated through `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship.

I have created a virtual attribute `:full_name` from the first model's(`User`) `:first_name` and `:last_name` attributes.

I am using ActiveAdmin, and trying to show the User's `:full_name` attribute in it's associated model's ActiveAdmin form.

I have checked in Rails console and found that `@user.full_name` is in existence.

In the User model, I have defined `full_name` using the information I found [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes) and [here](https://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/2010/07/21/add-model-virtual-attribute/).

Below is the code from the model and from it's associated model's(`Group`) admin/group.rb page.

```
# user.rb
def full_name
  [first_name, last_name].join(' ')
end

def full_name=(name)
  split = name.split(' ', 2)
  self.first_name = split.first
  self.last_name = split.last
end

# admin/group.rb 
form do |f|     
  f.inputs 'Details' do
    f.input :description
    f.input :users, as: :check_boxes, collection: User.pluck(:full_name, :id)
    f.submit
  end
end
```

I am hoping to view a full name from the attributes  `first_name` and `last_name`.

With my code as it is, each User that appears in the form is labeled "full_name".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pluck`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck) grabs column directly from the database. You are getting this error since your `full_name` method is not a database column.

Change `User.pluck(:full_name, :id)` to

`User.select(:id, :first_name, :last_name).all.map{|u| [u.full_name, u.id] }`

Answer (score 0):

You can access you're `full_name` instance method by mapping like this

```
User.all.map { |x| [x.full_name, x.id] }
```